# Looking at specific error on formset.is_valid() on Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

One of my forms is failing, and I want to know why.

```
    if formset.is_valid() and formset.has_changed():
        formset.save()
    else:
        # do something.
```

What can I print or see from formset on the else part to see what the problem was?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simpler than you think it is. Just [use `formset.errors`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#formset-validation)

```
if formset.is_valid() and formset.has_changed():
    formset.save()
else:
    print formset.errors
```

Also, you might want to consider rendering the erroneous form to the template, so the browser can display the errors in the formset.